# Superset Flask OAuth client no redirect_uri

Tags: python, flask, apache-superset

I am trying to authenticate superset flask user with OAuth (`flask-oauthlib`) by having Django Oauth server. But, In flask config.py `OAUTH_PROVIDERS`, there is no redirect_uri for getting the temporary authorization code from the Django oauth server. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, for people facing this, the redirect uri has to be given in this format in your custom OAuth2 server `<your_application_client_domain>/oauth-authorized/<provider_name>`

For example, If I create an OAuth2 provider dictionary entry called `djangooauth` in flask settings with all credentials given  to it, the redirect uri to be given to the server while creating a client would be `<client-domain>/oauth-authorized/djangooauth`